# Typescript Promise with multiple return types not assignable

Tags: typescript

I have a React component with some functions to retrieve and create folder records. For example:

```
  handleCreateFolder = (params: object) => {
        return this._performRequest('post', params)
            .then((data: ListFolderType) => this._addFolder(data))
    };

   loadFolders() {
        return this._performRequest('get')
            .then((data: ApiResponseData<ListFolderType>) => this._setFolders(data))
    }

  _performRequest(method: string, ...args: Array<number | object>)  {
        return this.props.api[method](...args)
            .then((response: ApiResponse) => response.data as ApiResponseData<ListFolderType> | ListFolderType)
  }
```

The `api` prop is a wrapper for Axios and exposes functions for the HTTP verbs that return `Promises`.

My `_performRequest` function is responsible for making the API call and returning the `data` key from the `response` object. The `data` here can be either a single `ListFolderType` or an array of folders whose type is called `ApiResponseData<ListFolderType>`.

Typescript complains with the following error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(data: ApiResponseData<ListFolderType>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ListFolderType | ApiResponseData<ListFolderType>) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'ListFolderType | ApiResponseData<ListFolderType>' is not assignable to type 'ApiResponseData<ListFolderType>'.
      Type 'ListFolderType' is missing the following properties from type 'ApiResponseData<ListFolderType>': records, meta

    .then((data: ApiResponseData<ListFolderType>) => this._setFolders(data))
```

How would I properly type that the `_performRequest` function can return one of two types but each of the respective `handleCreateFolder` and `loadFolders` promise functions accept only a single type?

Comment: Make _performRequest generic.